# How to display a graph with 5 variables?

Tags: graphing-functions

I am working on a project and I need to display to my professor the following data involved with communication theory.
I did an experiment varying distance(1/2/3/4 feet), delay amount between transmission, and block length (the length of the messages transmitted, ex. 1/2/4/8/16 bytes) and I calculated the bit error rate and byte error rate. What do you guys think would be the best way to display this information?

**Clarification:**
So, for further clarification, the experiment goes something like this. I set up the receiver and transmitter one foot away from each other. Then I transmit a block of data, each a single byte, with 1 millisecond delay between each block. Then 2nd experiment is same one byte transmission with 2 ms delay. And i go up to 4 ms delay. Then, I transmit a new block, with each block being 2 bytes, and i restart from 1 millisecond delay between each BLOCK (not byte). Then I work my way up to 4 ms delay again. Now I repeat this for a block length of 1 byte, 2, 4, 8, 16. So that's a total of 20 experiments. Then, i increase the distance to 2 feet, and i repeat this whole process. Then I increase to 3 feet, then to 4. This is the experiment. Please let me know if I need to give more clarification.

So i have 3 independent variables. Delay amount, block length, distance. I want to see the dependencies between these 3 variables (as suggested by my professor) to gain channel characteristics.

The dependent variable is the bit error rate and the byte error rate.

Comment: You need to tell us about the variable dependencies. For example, given distance and message length --> bit error rate also,  given distance and message length --> byte error rate? If so, you can have 2 curves on the same graph with axis being distance and the other axis being the message length.

Comment: Maybe you could use https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Present-your-data-in-a-surface-chart-1050ffc6-6143-4ee7-82b3-421bea88a1e8?CorrelationId=da639fc2-a89d-4de5-b8a6-46054e15a4f1&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US or https://plot.ly/plot

Comment: but with a 3D plot, i have 2 independent variables and 1 dependent variable i believe. but I'm guessing i need to plot 3 independent variables and how they affect 1 dependent variable.

Comment: I could have 2 dependent variables affecting one dependent variable. But that would mean 20 different graphs for each distance amount. and i have 4 distance amounts. So it'd probably be hard for a person to look at the data and analyze it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out. I'm going to keep one variable constant, the block length. The x variable could be the delay and the left side as the BER. Then 4 different colored curves. Then i could represent all the data in 5 graphs!